# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2-2)^2-(\frac{1}{x^2}-2)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

Assuming that the integrals below exist, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
Use the above relation to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2-2)^2-(\frac{1}{x^2}-2)^2}dx$$
Express the result in terms of the gamma function.\

I have tried expanding the terms in the exponent and factoring out a constant but i can't seem to get it in terms of a gamma function. Here's what i've tried so far:\

Exp$[-(x^2-2)^2-(\frac{1}{x^2}-2)^2]$=Exp$[-x^4+4x^2-\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{4}{x^2}-8]$\

Now rearranging terms and factoring out the constant gives:
$$e^{-8}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^4+\frac{1}{x^4})}e^{4(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})}dx$$
Next i said: $(x^4+\frac{1}{x^4})=(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2-2$. So we can rewrite out integral as:

$$e^{-8}e^{-2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2}e^{4(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})}dx=e^{-10}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2+4(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})}dx$$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Can i use that given relation and make substitution $u=x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$? Then i would have:

$$e^{-10}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2-4u}du$$

This doesn't seem right... \

The other thing i tried is to let $u=x^2$ so that $x=u^{1/2}$ and $dx=\frac{1}{2}u^{1/2-1}$. In this case the integral can be written as:

$$\frac{e^{-10}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(u+\frac{1}{u})^2+4(u+\frac{1}{u})}u^{1/2-1}du$$

Now we have it sort of looking like the gamma function but i don't know what to do with all the terms over "e".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = (x^2-2)^2+(x^{-2}-2)^2$.  Observe that $$g(x) = (x - x^{-1})^4 + 2,$$ so that the choice $f(x) = e^{-(x^4+2)}$ gives $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^{-g(x)} \, dx = e^{-2} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x-x^{-1})^4) \, dx = e^{-2} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^4} \, dx.$$  Then all that remains is to perform the final integration.  To this end, consider the substitution $$u = x^m, \quad x = u^{1/m}, \quad dx = \frac{1}{m} u^{-1+1/m} \, du$$ for $m > 0$.  Then $$\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^m} \, dx = \frac{1}{m} \int_{u=0}^\infty u^{-1+1/m} e^{-u} \, du = \frac{1}{m} \Gamma(1/m) = \Gamma(1 + 1/m).$$  For $m = 4$, we finally obtain the desired result $$2 e^{-2} \Gamma(5/4).$$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Never occurred to me that i could rewrite the terms in the exponent like that. Though i should have seen it as a binomial expansion. One question though; could you explain how you changed the bounds from $-\infty\rightarrow\infty$ to $0\rightarrow\infty$? Is that where the "2" came from in the solution? Something about the function being even so we can say that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=2\int_0^{\infty}f(x)$. Is that what happened?

Comment: @IronCharioteer Yes, exactly.  Due to the symmetry of the integrand, it suffices to consider the definite integral on the nonnegative real line; then the original integral is simply twice the result.

Comment: Great. Thank you for you help :)